# newly added files don't sync down

Tags: ubuntu-one

I added some files into my `Ubuntu One/My Files` folder on my desktop machine.  I can see them in the U1 web ui.  My laptop is connected to the same U1 account, and in the Ubuntu One preference pane I can see it's connected to the account.

However, my new files never download.

In `syncdaemon.log` I can see it checking a bunch of other existing files, and then the file ends with many repetitions of

```
2011-01-04 11:05:42,277 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.Main - NOTE - ---- MARK (state: <State: 'READY'  (queues WORKING_ON_METADATA  connection 'Not User With Network')>; queues: metadata: 1; content: 0; hash: 0, fsm-cache: hit=5086 miss=69) ----
```

I do have a working network connection.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your syncdaemon isn't connecting. Please file a bug with details as to versions, etc.; in the meanwhile, you can connect manually entering `u1sdtool -c` in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that got it going, and I filed http://pad.lv/697108